How do I catch a cookie sent as httponly in angular?
I have a webapi where I do a login process and after I do the login process, I get a response.
There is no token in the headers section of this response. But when I check the headers in the browser, I see a token as Set-Cookie and I can see this token in cookies as httponly
How can I access this Set-Cookiese or httponly cookies with angular?
I tried to reach out through the response through normal ways, but unfortunately it didn't work

The "httponly" flag means that the browser will not let JavaScript code on the client access the cookie value. So, you cannot do it.

You can't access an HTTP-Only cookie in client-side code, however if you're serving your Angular app via Node or .NET, you can access the cookie
